# I wrote a for loop which is going in reverse order from i=n-1 to i=0 and in it i call a vector ans2 but the vector is in reverse order why?

Tags: c++, vector, stack

In this part of code why i do push_back for ans2 it is doing in reverse order. What i know is when you push back in vector it start from 0 index and then add element to 1 and so on but here it is doing in opposite way it is adding first element in n-1 index and last to index 0

```
vector<int>ans2;
    stack<pair<int,int>>st2;
    for (int i = n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (st2.empty())
        {
            ans2.push_back(-1);
        }
        else if (!st2.empty() && q[i]>st2.top().first)
        {
            ans2.push_back(st2.top().second);
        }
        else if (!st2.empty() && q[i]<=st2.top().first)
        {
            while (!st2.empty() && q[i]<=st2.top().first)
            {
                st2.pop();
            }
            if (st2.empty())
            {
                ans2.push_back(-1);
            }
            else if (q[i]>st2.top().first)
            {
                ans2.push_back(st2.top().second);
            }
            
        }
        st2.push({q[i],i});
        
    }
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Did you write this code?

Comment: yes i wrote this code for nearest smaller right problem

Comment: I also don't understand the question. With that said you could use a debugger and step through your code line by line looking at the vectors at each step to see what it is actually doing.  If you have access to Visual Studio it will easily let you do that. Learn what the F9, F10 and F11 keys do as these will be the most important keys for stepping line by line and stopping at a line of your choice.

Comment: push_back() inserts an element at the end of the vector. If you iterate the original vector backwards then push_back to a different / initially empty vector as you iterate the resulting vector will be in reverse order from the first.

Comment: what is know is push_back() add element to back of the vector so why the vector is getting reverse

Comment: I explained that in my modified comment. With that said I do recommend you using a debugger and if you don't have one use some std::cout statements to print the items that  you are putting into the vector.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but those calls to `!st2.empty()` in the `else if` branches aren't needed. The `if(st2.empty())` handles that.